# How to retrieve ACL in documentum 7.1 via CMIS

Tags: java, cmis, documentum, apache-chemistry

I need to set specific ACLs to documents, those ACLs are created like:

```
PREFIX + ID
```

and now I need to set X ACL to Y document, but I haven't found a way of how to query or retrieve any ACL, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Bulk update ACLs can be done via DQL in the following way

update doc_type objects [(ALL)] set acl_name='YOUR_ACL' set
acl_domain='YOUR_ACL_DOMAIN' where .... YOUR QUALIFICATION

Hope this helps

Comment: I think OP was asking for CMIS approach to it?